# Bundle extra = data.getExtras() get nothing after using camera takes photo

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-camera, bundle

I'm new to Android developing and following the training course on google now, I meet a problem. After executing Bundle `extra = data.getExtras()`, extra is null. Also it will throw a nullpointerexception before I add the code `"if(extra!=null)"`
Here is the code of onActivityResult() method

[image]

Here is the code part to start the camera and save photo locally

[image]

All my code follows the training course and I am confused where is wrong. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: put your code here, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `onActivityResult()`, the result from capture photo doesn't response an image. It returns a Uri that you passed in `photo_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, <<uri>>)`. So please declare the `<<uri>>` as global then you can get this value in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: I think you are right and now I find it returns a Uri, I think I am going to fix it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @smilebuz How is the result?

Comment: Now I can display this message correctly, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                return;
            }
        } else {
           Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photo = new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                            "Journal" + Utils_class.getID() + ".jpeg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photo));
                    mSelectedFilePath = photo.getAbsolutePath();
                    startActivityForResult(intent,
                            ACTION_TAKE_PICTURE);
                }

        }

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       if (requestCode == ACTION_TAKE_PICTURE) {
                    // flag = true;
                    // new Utils();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        checkPermissionForStorageForCam();
                    } else {

                        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                    }


                } 

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: @smilebuz You have to check whether its marshmellow or not. if marsh mellow means you have get permission on run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the extra parameter `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` with the camera intent then camera activity will write the captured image to that path and it will not return the bitmap in the onActivityResult method.

If you will check the path which you are passing then you will know that actually camera had write the captured file in that path.